# Copy MySQL Workbench query output to clipboard

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've used Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and one feature allowed me to run an SQL script and copy the output table to my clipboard. Something like this:

[image]

When I right click on my output table in MySQL Workbench, I can only copy the row content.

Does anyone know how to copy the whole table including headers?

Comment: I should also mention that I cannot Ctrl+A on the table because this does not highlight all cells.

Answer (score 23):

Follow these steps in the workbench to get the data and the header rows into Excel.

1. Click on the box to the left of the first column on any data record.
2. Click on the header on the box to the left of the column headers.
3. Do a Ctrl+C to copy the data to the clipboard.
4. Do a Ctrl+V to paste the data to your excel file.

Like so:

[image: Visual Example for Step 1 & 2]

Comment: You wizard! Take my up-vote. Awesome visual instructions btw.

Comment: This saves my life. Why doesn't set as right answer ?

Comment: Thanks! This is so weird that they make you click twice to get the headers to paste.

Comment: Although it worked for me in Windows 10, it didn't work for me in Ubuntu 20.04. In this case, I needed to use Ctrl-A to select all the cells, then right-click them, and choose "Copy row (with names, tab separated)" and then paste into Google Sheets.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the cell contents are very long and only part of the result is showing with an ellipsis at the end, this method will copy the data showing as well as the ellipsis, not the true results.

Answer (score 3):

You may have an old version of MySQL Workbench. I can press Ctrl+A on Win or Cmd+A on Mac to select all records. Then Ctrl/Cmd+C to copy to clipboard (or use the "Copy Row" entry which should probably just be named "Copy").

Comment: I have version 5.2.38 running on Ubuntu.

Comment: Then upgrade to 6.3.3 and see if that fixes the problem for you.

Comment: This doesn't also copy the headers though.

Answer (score 1):

**If the data you are trying to copy is being truncated with an ellipsis:**

Vishal's answer is absolutely correct:

> 1. Click on the box to the left of the first column on any data record.
> 2. Click on the header on the box to the left of the column headers. Do a
> 3. Ctrl+C to copy the data to the clipboard. Do a Ctrl+V to paste the
> 4. data to your excel file.

But if the cells content exceeds the maximum number of bytes configured in the `Max. Field Value Length to Display in (in bytes)` setting, this will copy only the content showing including the ellipsis.

This setting is located at *Edit > Preferences > SQL Editor > SQL Execution*

[image]

If the results are being truncated, in order to copy the entire result, adjust this value to whatever size you need to display to full cell contents for copying, or set a value of `-1` to avoid truncation.

Answer (score 0):

In the Workbench you go to File > Export > Forward Engine SQL CREATE Script and this will guide you through three easy steps to create the SQL script for the complete shema.

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot of mysql workbench corresponding to the info below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6H2L.png)

On Mac, hit cmd+a to select all

Then right-click and select "copy row (with names, tab separated)"

This will copy all of the data in the rows, as well as the header/column names. And it will be formatted to past into excel.

I assume this would work similarly on Windows, but I can't confirm that since I only have a Mac.